# Script to locate all remote local drives and then check top level directories

Tags: powershell, remote-access

I'm trying to figure out how to locate, on remote servers, ONLY local disks and then look at their top level directories. This is what I have so far:

```
foreach ($i in Get-Content "U:\Powershell\Lists\Servers.txt")
    {$i + "`n" + "=========================="; [System.IO.DriveInfo]::getdrives() | Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq 'Fixed'}}
```

I believe that this returns only the local server's local disks, but this is also the closest I've come to figuring out what I want to see. Also not entirely sure how I'd take those results and then perform a Get-ChildItem against those drives listed. I'm still fairly new to PS scripting, so any explanation would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to setup [WinRM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384372(v=vs.85).aspx) Service for this.

```
$DriveInformation = @()
$servers = Get-Content "U:\Powershell\Lists\Servers.txt" | % {
    $invoke = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ {
        [System.IO.DriveInfo]::getdrives() | ? {$_.DriveType -eq 'Fixed'} | 
            % {  gci $_.Name | ? {$_.PSIsContainer} }
    }
    $DriveInformation += $Invoke
}
```

First we're creating an array which will contain the Drive Information at the end, then we're reading in all servernames with `get-content`, loop over it with `foreach-object` alias `%` to get the servernames. Then we're invoking the command to read the drive information on each server with `invoke-command`, inside the `invoke-command` scriptblock the local drives get selected and for each selected drive we're doing a `get-childitem` a.k.a `gci` to get the top level directories (only directories. if you want the files also, delete `| ? {$_.PSIsContainer}`)

if you want to export the data, just use:

```
$DriveInformation | out-file "U:\somepath\somename.txt" -force
```

and put it at the end of your script